# What is the smallest number of $45^\circ$–$60^\circ$–$75^\circ$ triangles in non-trivial substitution tiling?

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, fractals, tiling

Let **base** = $45^\circ$–$60^\circ$–$75^\circ$ triangle.

Over at [What is the smallest number of **base**s that a square can be divided into?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44684/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-45-circ-60-circ-75-circ-triangles-that-a-squ) it was determined that ***23*** base were needed to make a $45^\circ$–$45^\circ$–$90^\circ$ triangle.

[image: Sqrt into 45-60-75]

How about non-trivial dissections of **base** into similar triangles?  Start with **base** and divide it into smaller copies of **base**. Ideally the method should be specific to **base** and wouldn't work with other triangles. Also, at least one of the internal triangles should have no edges parallel to the original triangle.

What are the simplest non-trivial dissections of **base** into similar triangles?

Comment: For clarification, does "non-trivial" mean all the three triangles at the three corners cannot be parallel triangles to the original one? Or does it mean at least one cannot be parallel? Or at least two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm... This doesn't *exactly* fit your criterion in that it's not unique to the $45^∘–60^∘–75^∘$ triangle, but the central triangle here has no edges parallel to the edges of the original triangle.

[image]

The vertices are: 
$$ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{0,0\} \\ 
 \{1,0\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{22} \left(21-2 \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{22} \left(6+\sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{-\frac{3}{22}
   \left(-5+\sqrt{3}\right),0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{22} \left(6+\sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{22}
   \left(6+\sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{286} \left(237-43 \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{143} \left(21-2 \sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
   \left\{\frac{1}{286} \left(216-41 \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{22} \left(6+\sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
   \left\{\frac{1}{286} \left(174-37 \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{286} \left(36+17 \sqrt{3}\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{996-197 \sqrt{3}}{1430},\frac{192+43 \sqrt{3}}{1430}\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{996-197
   \sqrt{3}}{1430},\frac{306+73 \sqrt{3}}{1430}\right\} \\ \left\{\frac{1}{130} \left(102-19
   \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{318+31 \sqrt{3}}{1430}\right\} \\
\end{array}
 $$

This is based on the three *other* four-self-similar-triangle dissections beyond the usual midpoints-of-the-sides one:

[image]

Comment: I think this answers the question completely (answer is $4$), unless the OP wishes to exclude this and consider it trivial.

Comment: Yes, looks like that will do it.