# Smallest number of $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangles that tile a rectangle

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, tiling

In this wonderful [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44684/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-45-circ-60-circ-75-circ-triangles-that-a-squ) we learned that a square can be divided into forty six $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangles.

Now I am wondering what is the smallest number of $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangles that can tile some **rectangle**? In other words, from all tilings of rectangles with such triangles, I am looking for the one with the smallest number of triangles.

Comment: I do not think this is even possible for an arbitrary rectangle. Do you have a reason to suspect that such a tiling exists in the case of a rectangle whose sides have an irrational ratio?

Comment: No you misunderstood. For all possible tilings of rectangles I am looking for the one with the smallest number of triangles.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Clearly all rectangles with rational ratio between the side has a solution - not sure that this is the minimal.

Comment: How many triangles do we need for such solutions?

Comment: Is there a nice app for testing out ideas? I tried GeoGebra, but adding a new triangle takes quite a few steps (`Angle with given size`x2+`Ray`x2+`Intersection`). Doing the calculations by hand is very tedious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Here's my 18-triangle solution.

From the coordinates, it seems the width/height ratio of the rectangle is 138/(96+6√₃) or (16-√₃)/11 which is about 1.297

### How

[image]

Using my code from answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4309114/406098), I checked for 5-sided polygons that have 45-degree, 90-degree, 45-degree angles in sequence, with equal lengths for the (parallel) "45-degree" sides.

I was happy to find that a simple solution exists!

### Coordinates

```
27+6√₃,48+3√₃
63-9√₃,33+15√₃
36+8√₃,36+8√₃
27+6√₃,69
27+6√₃,27+6√₃
0,63-9√₃
0,96+6√₃
0,0
84-12√₃,0
75+9√₃,63-9√₃
138,0
111-6√₃,48+3√₃
102-8√₃,60-2√₃
111-6√₃,27+6√₃
111-6√₃,69
138,33+15√₃
138,96+6√₃
54+12√₃,96+6√₃
{{0,1,2},{3,1,0},{4,0,2},{5,4,3},{6,3,5},{7,5,4},{7,8,2},{8,9,1},{10,9,8},{11,9,12},{13,9,11},{14,11,12},{15,14,13},{10,13,15},{16,15,14},{16,17,12},{17,1,9},{6,1,17}}
```

### Larger solutions

[image]

20 triangles (48 by 30+6√₃)

[image]

22 triangles (772 by 402+54√₃)

[image]

22 triangles (222 by 228-30√₃)

Comment: Nice! This may not be minimal though.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear that at least 12 triangles are needed just to complete the perimeter, so proving a minimal solution *might* be within reach.

Comment: Perhaps. Is it clear that the number should be even?

Comment: Hmm, great question. I have no idea.

I also wonder if you need exactly two interior vertices where 5 triangles meet.

Comment: (To clarify "at least 12 triangles are needed to complete the perimeter": each side of the rectangle needs at least one vertex (which will have 3 incident triangles), because a single triangle edge can't span an entire side of the rectangle. A triangle corner at a rectangle corner must be 45 degrees.)

Comment: I understood where $12$ came from. It is probably clear that the number is at least $14$. But the cases $15,16,17$ are not clear at all.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you Tom!

Comment: Did you specifically search for symmetric solutions? Are there any non-symmetric solutions?

Comment: I only searched for a special 5-sided polygon that covers exactly half the rectangle in a symmetrical way (see "How").

Yeah, there a lot of ways to break symmetry. For example, any 45-60-75 triangle can be replaced with 4 smaller 45-60-75 triangles. Maybe the optimal solution for tiling a rectangle or square is non-symmetric.

Comment: re "I also wonder if you need exactly two interior vertices where 5 triangles meet": Yes!*

Perimeter of square will have exactly 8 more 45-degree angles than 75-degree angles. So opposite must be true on interior, which can only be accomplished by two 75-75-75-75-60-degree "junctions". 

*Assuming you don't add 45-45-45-45 junctions along the square's perimeter.