# What are non-trivial dissections of a $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangle into smaller $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangles?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, tiling

At [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44684/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-45-circ-60-circ-75-circ-triangles-that-a-squ/4309114), a square is divided into $45^\circ-60^\circ-75^\circ$ triangles in various ways.  To solve that problem, several people built databases of shapes that could be built with that triangle. Since a lot of effort went into those databases, this question is meant to mine out some of the existing interesting data.

I would like to see a few of the other possibilities for use in substitution tilings.